# How to represent "to be approved" elements in database

Tags: php, database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

I have a model where it has an attribute called *type* that is a type of a *user*'s *bag* (substitute entities for confidentiality).

- `Users` can have multiple `Bag`s (one to many)
- `Bags` have only one `Type`
- `Type` has fields `name` and `description`
- a `Bag`'s `Type` can either be:

  - chosen from a predetermined set of values; or

    - I will preload these in the database
  - specified by user

    - if `User` application is approved, then their custom `Type` is added to the predetermined set.

Basically a new `Type`'s existence depends on the `User`'s approval status.

---

I want to ask what is an ideal way to represent the relationship of these three objects.

Here is my strategy:

- `Bag` has the `id` of a `User`
- `Bag` has the `id` of a `Type`
- populate `Type` table with the predetermined values, and return to view for `User` to chose from

the set of rules above is ready-to-go if the `Type`s are predetermined.

The challenge is when there are *to be approved* values.

To handle the new `Type`s,

- all custom `Type`s **will still be added** to the `Type` table
- `Type` table will have `approved` and `date_approved` field

  - if predetermined, then their values will be `1` and the current database upload/default time respectively.
  - if new, then their values will be null at first but will be updated once `User` who specified them is approved.

    - I will `select` them from the `Bag` and `join` with the `User` to get these values

---

Here are my sample tables:

```
TABLE user {
    id PK,
    approved TINYINT,
    date_approved DATETIME
}

TABLE bag {
    id PK,
    id_user FK REFERENCES user(id) NOT NULL,
    id_type FK REFERENCES type(id) NOT NULL
}

TABLE type {
    id PK,
    name NOT NULL,
    description NOT NULL,
    approved TINYINT NOT NULL,
    date_approved DATETIME NOT NULL
}
```

---

Is my proposed solution okay or can you please suggest a better way to deal with such business logic?

Answer (score 1):

In your definition a bag can only has one user and one type, so it's nothing more than the link table for the n:m relation between user and type. Looks like that is your intention. 
No need though for the USER's fields, because they are only attributes of TYPE

```
approved TINYINT,
date_approved DATETIME
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem, which has an equally common mathematical solution that is implemented in nearly every language. In sum, that is to combine the two disparate groups into "sets," and then to apply either a symmetric differencing, differencing, an intersection, or a union operation on the two sets. I'm sure you can figure out the one you want, but here's **all** of them to meet all needs so related:

Symmetric difference modifies the first set such that it equals ((A - B) U (B - A)), where A is the first set and B is other set. The other set is the set that should have the symmetric difference calculated from [see symmetricDifferenceSet code, *below*; if you do not want to modify the original set, but create a new set instead, see my code provided in createSymmetricDifferenceSet, *also below*].

The **difference** (or **minus**), **intersect** and **union** operations should already be familiar to you.

Here's how these operations are performed in Objective-C (your implementation may *slightly* differ):

```
- (void) symmetricDifferenceSet:(NSMutableSet *)otherSet {

    NSMutableSet * copySet = [self copy];

    [copySet minusSet:otherSet];
    [otherSet minusSet:self];
    [self unionSet:copySet];
}

- (NSMutableSet *) createSymmetricDifferenceSet:(NSMutableSet *)otherSet {

    NSMutableSet * copySet = [self copy];

    [copySet minusSet:otherSet];
    [otherSet minusSet:self];
    [copySet unionSet:otherSet];

    return copySet;
}

- (NSMutableSet *) createMinusSet:(NSMutableSet *)otherSet {

    NSMutableSet * copySet = [self copy];

    [copySet minusSet:otherSet];

    return  copySet;
}

- (NSMutableSet *) createIntersectionSet:(NSMutableSet *)otherSet {

    NSMutableSet * copySet = [self copy];

    [copySet intersectSet:otherSet];

    return  copySet;
}

- (NSMutableSet *) createUnionSet:(NSMutableSet *)otherSet {

    NSMutableSet * copySet = [self copy];

    [copySet unionSet:otherSet];

    return  copySet;
}
```

I don't know SQL like I used to; but, the equivalent of the above can be ascertained from W3Schools.com. For example, at [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL5UX-p1wMc):

> SQL UNION Operator The SQL UNION operator combines the result of two
>   or more SELECT statements.
>
> Notice that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same
>   number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types.
>   Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.
>
> SQL UNION Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

> Note: The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To
>   allow duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION.
>
> SQL UNION ALL Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

> PS: The column names in the result-set of a UNION are usually equal to
>   the column names in the first SELECT statement in the UNION.

YouTube users have posted a plethora of videos on these particular operations; see [SQL Intersect, Union, Union All, Minus, and Except](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL5UX-p1wMc) for an example.